# MySQL: I would like to export the "description" of the MySQL Server variables to a csv

Tags: mysql, my.ini

I need a CSV with all the MySQL Server Variables and a **basic description** of what the variable means. Like you can find here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html

I know how to get the Server Variables + values, but I want an **extra column** behind it, with the **description** of what it means.

The MySQL workbench program, has these values, see "*Status and System variables*" but when I copy these lines and paste them in a spreadheet, only the names and values are pasted, but not the description.

I have not been able to find it on google or this forum. Strange because I would suspect others could have had this question before.

Thank for your help.

Comment: mysql not store internal description of variables, all information on links You already check. So nobody not try to do this, just because it not necessary

Comment: I do not think it is available.

Comment: Web scraping is the best I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution: I installed the MySQL Workbench on Windows 10.

In the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules` you will find the file: `wb_admin_variable_list.py`. By editing this script I have been able to create an CSV file from it, which I could import in my DB. Now I can get the Server Variables and have an description of them in my DB.

If there is a place where I could upload this CSV file, then I could share the file with you.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: If you want to share the file, you could create a github public repository.